# Lower case all words inside square brackets in a string PHP

Tags: php, regex, string, preg-replace

I have a string in PHP like 'Hello [FIRSTNAME] [LASTNAME]' I want to convert all characters inside brackets into lower case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace_callback](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php):

```
<?php
$text="Hello [FIRSTNAME]";
echo preg_replace_callback('/\b([^]]+)\b/', function ($word) {
      return strtolower($word[1]);
 }, $text);
```

Comment: Thank to akam here is a working solution `$text="Hello [FIRSTNAME][LASTNAME]TEST"; echo preg_replace_callback('/[\[{\(].*?[\]}\)]/', function ($word) {       return strtolower($word[0]);  }, $text); – 
`